# animation nodes bool difference union intersect

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes

How to do Boolean mesh operations with animation nodes (difference, union, intersect)?

The Boolean nodes for animation nodes seem to be for manipulating lists of numbers not mesh data?

Comment: Maybe you should give a look here https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5ABAuGEvBMmau-1xJsNw6w and here https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes I am aware there is a user manual and have checked it before posting this question. The closest thing I can find is the https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/mesh/join_mesh_data_list.html "Join Mesh Data" list function. The other Boolean functions in the manual do not seem to be related to mesh Booleans but rather math Booleans for lists of numbers (as stated in the original question).

Comment: The youtube link seems to be a demo reel?

Comment: [Sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) has a boolean node. Get the `b28_prelease_master` branch for 2.80

Comment: Thanks I've tried the Sverchok boolean node - it works good. This question is specifically for "Animation Nodes". I'm comparing animation nodes to sverchok at the moment and they both have strengths and weaknesses it seems. It seems strange that animation nodes doesn't have a "mesh boolean" function... or at least I can't find a way to do difference, union, intersect mesh functions in animation nodes.